# ¿Cómo obtener la referencia o el valor de una variable sabiendo únicamente su nombre?

Tags: c#, variables, diccionarios

Actualmente utilizo un `Enum` junto a un diccionario para poder identificar cada uno de los diferentes cursores que utiliza mi aplicación:

```
Dictionary<CursorShape, Cursor> cursors = new Dictionary<CursorShape, Cursor>
{
    { CursorShape.None, Cursors.None },
    { CursorShape.Arrow, Cursors.Arrow },
    { CursorShape.IBeam, Cursors.IBeam },
    { CursorShape.Cross, Cursors.Cross },
    { CursorShape.SizeNS, Cursors.SizeNS },
    { CursorShape.SizeWE, Cursors.SizeWE },
    { CursorShape.SizeNESW, Cursors.SizeNESW },
    { CursorShape.SizeNWSE, Cursors.SizeNWSE },
    { CursorShape.Hand, Cursors.Hand },
    { CursorShape.Wait, Cursors.Wait }
};

private void SetCursorShape(CursorShape shape)
{
    this.Cursor = cursors[shape];
}
```

El tipo de cursor a usar me viene a través de un socket que es el que especifica la siguiente forma del cursor, es por esto que no utilizo directamente la clase `System.Windows.Input.Cursors`.

Si son pocos elementos como los que meciono arriba si que resulta sencillo ponerlos uno debajo del otro, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de simplificarlo para cuando me enfrente a un problema similar con muchos más valores.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar la respuesta a mi pregunta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053532), sería utilizando [reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection), el cual tiene un coste superior a si llamase directamente al método. El código que hay que usar no es muy bonito y quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
private void SetCursorShape(CursorShape shape)
{
    this.Cursor = (Cursor)typeof(Cursors).GetProperty(shape.ToString()).GetValue(Cursor, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pruebe este método:

```
this.Cursor = Enum.TryParse(shape.ToString(), out Cursors myStatus) 
                  ? myStatus 
                  : Cursors.None;
```

Más ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104/999428

Comment: Hola @Ryan, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Por desgracia no funciona ya que esos métodos solo sirven para transformar de un Enum a otro equivalente, es decir, que tenga los mismos nombres para cada valor. En mi caso estoy utilizando variables estáticas de la clase Cursors.